# Delete nested items from JSON variable

Tags: python, json

First of all - I am not a Python Guru, just learning.

I have a code, which parse all the issues from my personal Jira space into one big JSON variable.
I would like to remove unnecessary nested fields, like `createdAt`, etc.

Do you have a solution, how to do that?

That is a sample of the output I have:

```
{
    "expand": "names,schema",
    "issues": [
        {
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "fields": {
                "assignee": {
                    "active": true,
                    "avatarUrls": {
                        "16x16": "https://jira.link.se/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=6559",
                        "24x24": "https://jira.link.se/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=6559",
                        "32x32": "https://jira.globalrelay.net/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=6559",
                        "48x48": "https://jira.link.se/secure/useravatar?avatarId=6559"
                    },
                    "displayName": "Vasiliy Utkin",
                    "emailAddress": "Vasiliy@utkin.net",
                    "key": "JIRAHUIRA221",
                    "name": "uassya@link.se",
                    "self": "https://jira.link.se/rest/api/2/user?username=uassya@utkin.net",
                    "timeZone": "America/Toronto"
                },
                "status": {
                    "description": "",
                    "iconUrl": "https://jira.link.se/images/icons/statuses/open.png",
                    "id": "6559",
                    "name": "To Do",
                    "self": "https://jira.link.se/rest/api/2/status/6559",
                    "statusCategory": {
                        "colorName": "default",
                        "id": 2,
                        "key": "new",
                        "name": "To Do",
                        "self": "https://jira.link.se/rest/api/2/statuscategory/2"
                    }
                },
                **"summary": "Jumping over the tree"**
            },
            "id": "2234",
            "key": "XXX-1",
            "self": "https://jira.link.se/rest/api/2/issue/6559"
        }
    ],
[
        {
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "fields": {
                "assignee": {
                    "active": true,
                    "avatarUrls": {
                        "16x16": "https://jira.link.se/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=6559",
                        "24x24": "https://jira.link.se/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=6559",
                        "32x32": "https://jira.globalrelay.net/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=6559",
                        "48x48": "https://jira.link.se/secure/useravatar?avatarId=6559"
                    },
                    "displayName": "Vasiliy Utkin",
                    "emailAddress": "Vasiliy@utkin.net",
                    "key": "JIRAHUIRA221",
                    "name": "uassya@link.se",
                    "self": "https://jira.link.se/rest/api/2/user?username=uassya@utkin.net",
                    "timeZone": "America/Toronto"
                },
                "status": {
                    "description": "",
                    "iconUrl": "https://jira.link.se/images/icons/statuses/open.png",
                    "id": "6559",
                    "name": "To Do",
                    "self": "https://jira.link.se/rest/api/2/status/6559",
                    "statusCategory": {
                        "colorName": "default",
                        "id": 2,
                        "key": "new",
                        "name": "To Do",
                        "self": "https://jira.link.se/rest/api/2/statuscategory/2"
                    }
                },
                **"summary": "Jumping over the tree"**
            },
            "id": "2234",
            "key": "XXX-1",
            "self": "https://jira.link.se/rest/api/2/issue/6559"
        }
    ],
    "maxResults": 50,
    "startAt": 0,
    "total": 2
}
```

What I tried - there is my code:

```
json_obj = json.loads(printInfo)

del json_obj["expand"]
del json_obj["maxResults"]
del json_obj["startAt"]
del json_obj["total"]
```

These lines could delete all the first level fields, but not nested. I tried to find the way how to delete the nested values, but unsuccessfully.

I tried to do some weird code like that:

`del json_obj[{'issues': {'expand'}}]`

But it wasn't working as well.

Expected output is a new JSON with data from sample input:

```
{
    "active": true,
    "displayName": "Vasiliy Utkin",
    "emailAddress": "Vasiliy@utkin.net",
    "name": "To Do",\*\*
    "key": "new",
    "name": "To Do",
    "summary": "Jumping over the tree"
    "key": "XXX-1",
},
{
    "active": true,
    "displayName": "Vasiliy Utkin",
    "emailAddress": "Vasiliy@utkin.net",
    "name": "To Do",\*\*
    "key": "new",
    "name": "To Do",
    "summary": "Jumping over the tree"
    "key": "XXX-1",
}
```

And also I need to have a `key` value in an additional global variable.

Comment: `del json_obj['issues'][0]['expand']`

Comment: You delete it the same way you would print it. To access nested elements, you use more subscripts.

Comment: It's better to create a new record with the information you want to keep.  Also remember that the keys must be unique.  You have two `"name"` and two `"key"`, and that's not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

`issues` is a list, so loop over it and delete the nested keys.

```
for issue in json_obj['issues']:
    del issue['expand']
```

Comment: But that wouldn't work for third-forth level elements, isnt it?

Comment: No.  You would need to use recursion.

Comment: @TimRoberts, may I ask you to explain, how to write the right recursion for that?

Comment: You only need recursion if you don't know a priori where the record is located and you have to find it dynamically. But if you know where it is, you just write the appropriate nested keys, possibly using nested loops. @IvanA

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of extracting the information you want into a separate list.  Deleting is not enough for what you want, because you need to reorganize as well.  Notice that I have tweaked the keys to avoid duplicates.

```
import json

data = json.load(open('x.json'))

info = []
for row in data['issues']:
    rec = {
        'key': row['key'],
        'active': row['fields']['assignee']['active'],
        'displayName': row['fields']['assignee']['displayName'],
        'emailAddress': row['fields']['assignee']['emailAddress'],
        'status-name': row['fields']['status']['statusCategory']['name'],
        'status-key': row['fields']['status']['statusCategory']['key'],
        'summary': row['fields']['summary']
    }
    info.append( rec )

from pprint import pprint
pprint(info)
```

Output:

```
[{'active': True,
  'displayName': 'Vasiliy Utkin',
  'emailAddress': 'Vasiliy@utkin.net',
  'key': 'XXX-1',
  'status-key': 'new',
  'status-name': 'To Do',
  'summary': 'Jumping over the tree'}]
```

Comment: And what if I have more than one issue? Will the code work as well?

Comment: Did you even look at the code?  Do you see the `for` loop?

Comment: And that's why I asked. When I run this code with my data, I have an error:
```Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\\something.py", line 46, in <module>
"active": row["fields"]["assignee"]["active"],
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable```
So it looks like even if there is `for` loop, it wouldn't work for my data

Comment: Well, that tells us the records don't all look like what you've shown us.  Some records must not have a "fields" section or an "assignee" section.  That just means you need code to check for their presence first.